# Can scala's parser combinators parse binary files?

Tags: parsing, scala, binary

Can the built-in scala parser combinators parse binary (not text) files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can parse anything, that's why `type Elem` is abstract on `Parsers`.

Comment: I see. Odersky really put some thought into them. :)